# Laravel Dusk how to get multiple element's attributes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-5.8

I just began using Laravel Dusk on Laravel 5.8 and already faced an issue. Was searching a lot on Google, but haven't found an answer.

```
$browser->visit('https://www.website.com')
        ->script('window.scrollTo(0, 1000);');

$elems = $browser              
          ->pause(1000)
          ->elements('.elem a');
```

This is my current code to get all the links under a certain element on the page.

What I want to do is get all the links and get their `href` attribute or any custom attribute they might have (I want to specify the name if the attribute).

I have found this in the documentation:

```
$attribute = $browser->attribute('selector', 'value');
```

But it doesn't really help me because it only gets the first (or last, I'm not 100% sure) element's attribute.

So is there any way to iterate through the found elements and extract their attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getAttribute()`:

```php
foreach ($elems as $elem) {
    $elem->getAttribute('href');
}
```