# Laravel Dusk how to find elements inside elements?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8, Dusk. I would like to find certain elements inside a class.

So let's say I extracted every element on the page with the class of `selectable`.

```
$browser->visit('https://www.website.com')
        ->script('window.scrollTo(0, 10000);');

$elems = $browser              
          ->pause(1000)
          ->elements('.selectable');
```

After this I iterate through these elements like this:

```
foreach ($elems as $elem) {

}
```

The question is, how can I find every element with the class of `.custom-item` inside these `.selectable` classes. Additionally, I'd like to get one of `.custom-item`'s attribute. I used to get it like this:

```
$elem->getAttribute('custom-attribute');
```

(Learned from this [Laravel Dusk how to get multiple element's attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150671/laravel-dusk-how-to-get-multiple-elements-attributes) post)

So how can I find/extract elements inside elements and then get their custom attributes with Laravel Dusk?

Comment: Can you use `$browser->elements('.selectable .custom-item')`? Or does it have to be two steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel Dusk does not provide an API method to locate elements. You can do it by utilising the underlying webdriver API.

You can access the webdriver via

```
$browser->driver
```

And to find an element wihtin another element. You will probably need to approach it via xPath

```
$browser->driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath('//*[@class="selectable"][@class="custom-attribute"]'));
```

I made up xpath in above example. You can find the exact xpath by inspecting the element in chrome developer tool.

You can read more about selectors in Dusk here

https://www.5balloons.info/understanding-selectors-laravel-dusk-browser-testing/

Answer (score -1):

The easier way:

```
$advs = $browser->elements('CSS_SELECTOR');

foreach ($advs as $adv) {

   // for example
   $adv->click();

}
```

Comment: how am I supposed to find a specific name from the loop?