# Dusk: Loop on class of inputs can't enter text with sendKeys

Tags: laravel, css-selectors, laravel-dusk

I'm not able to enter text into a specific input box as determined by a data attribute.  There could be dozens of inputs with the same class, so I'd prefer not to add `dusk='xxxx'` all over the page.

For route and server-side efficiency, the AJAX function pulls a type from the array of inputs and routes to a function that branches the action.

**Blade code**:

```
{!! Form::text('question[]', null, 
         ['class'=>'form-control actionChange', "data-id"=>$question->id, "data-type"=>'question']) !!}
```

The page starts with other questions with a different type, so I have tried using `nth-child(x)` to grab the selector within the modal, but no success.  I've tried using `$browser->script()` as well.

Reading several similar questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55150671/laravel-dusk-how-to-get-multiple-elements-attributes), it appears that a loop within the modal is likely the best way to go.  This method correctly assigns the selector to the loop variable, `$input`.  It correctly `clear()`s data, and I've tested similar code with `click()` and it successfully works.  However, it will **not** enter data in the input.  `type()` and `keys()` don't appear to work with the `RemoteWebElement`, so I believe my only choice to enter data is `sendKeys()`.

**Dusk test code:**

```
$browser->assertPathIs('/notice')
        ->whenAvailable('.modal', function($modal) use($browser) {
           $modal->assertSee('Survey for:')
             ->waitFor('#heading')
             // WORKS fine
             ->keys('#heading', 'Edited Heading for Survey', '{enter}')
             ->waitFor('.actionSurvey');

                // Edit a question -- NOT WORKING
                foreach ($browser->elements('.actionChange') as $input) {
                    $dataType = $input->getAttribute('data-type');
                    if($dataType === 'question') {
                        $input->clear()  // WORKS Fine 
                            ->sendKeys('Edited_Question') // NOT successful
                        break;
```

I've tried with and without the `clear()` method, as well as various selector choices both within and out of the modal loop.  Same for `script()`  Also, tried using the `$modal` variable to get the elements, but this was just a guess as I'm a bit out of my depth of understanding at this point.

I probably fubar'd something basic, but I don't understand why one method works, and another doesn't on the same handle.

Comment: @Watercaymen Did you tried finding the element directly using the underlying driver $browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('input[data-id="3"]')) ?

Comment: @Tushar: thank you very much for your response.  You code correctly finds the element, like the loop above does (though yours is more efficient).  However, I get the **same result** - it can clear the input, but it will not send keys to the modal input.

Comment: @Watercaymen Hard to debug this without actually looking at the screen you are working on. One way to debug this would be to put $browser->tinker() just after the clear() method. And then you can try out different methods in the terminal of what is working and what isn't.

Comment: @Tushar.  WOW!  That is absolutely brilliant.  I didn't realise you could do this, but it is extremely helpful.  Thank you very much.  I have been able to use tinker using your code, but I'm getting the same results.  I am starting to think this may be an issue with dusk/selenium, as I can `clear()`, but nothing is allowing keys to be sent on the modal, even though the handle is correct.

Comment: Try upgrading the chrome-driver version if you are not on latest. I once had this crazy issue with driver not switching to iFrame and upgrading the chrome-driver fixed that.